# Namespace-only class visibility in C#/.NET?

Tags: c#, .net

In C#, can you make a class visible only within its own namespace without living in a different assembly? This seems useful for typical helper classes that shouldn't be used elsewhere.
(i.e. what Java calls package-private classes)

Comment: @nos: are you looking for the equivalent of java's package-level visibility?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I don't think that what you want is possible.

Answer (score 87):

You can make the classes `internal` but this only prevents anyone outside of the *assembly* from using the class.  But you still have to make a *separate assembly* for each namespace that you want to do this with. I'm assuming that is why you *wouldn't* want to do it.

**Getting the C# Compiler to Enforce Namespace Visibility**

There is an article here ([Namespace visibility in C#](http://fonp.blogspot.com/2008/12/namespace-visibility-in-c.html)) that shows a method of using partial classes as a form of "fake namespace" that you might find helpful.

The author points out that this doesn't work perfectly and he discusses the shortcomings. The main problem is that C# designers **designed C# *not* to work this way.** This deviates heavily from expected coding practices in C#/.NET, which is one of the .NET Frameworks greatest advantages.

It's a neat trick… now ***don't* do it.**

Comment: Just found an example: `System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application`

Comment: The article says that you have to prefix every call with your "namespace" name, but you don't need that with C# 6 "using static". You can make the "namespace" a static partial class and then in the client code write "using static"

Comment: @Pumkko The class doesn't need to be static to be able to use the 'using static' statement, though if you are using it as a namespace then it should be anyway.

Comment: I keep ending up back on this page because I keep hoping the answer will change, but alas: C# doesn't have namespace or package-level protection. You say C# is designed not to work this way, but I've never been able to find an answer as to *why* that is. Having a protection level that is accessible within a group of files but private outside of it is a powerful tool that leads to good architecture. Instead, C# tells you either that any class-to-class communication must be public to everyone, or otherwise just start nesting numerous classes inside of each other. It's very clumsy.

Answer (score 23):

internal is assembly (strictly speaking module) privacy. It has no effect on namespace visibility.

The only way to achieve privacy of a class from other classes within the same assembly is for a class to be an inner class.

At this point if the class is private it is invisible to anything not in that class or the outer class itself.

If protected it is visible to everyone that could see it when private but is also visible to sub classes of the outer class.

```
public class Outer
{
    private class Hidden     { public Hidden() {} }
    protected class Shady    { public Shady() {} }
    public class Promiscuous { public Promiscuous() {} }
}

public class Sub : Outer
{
    public Sub():base() 
    {
        var h = new Hidden();      // illegal, will not compile
        var s = new Shady();       // legal
        var p = new Promiscuous(); // legal
    }
}

public class Outsider 
{
    public Outsider() 
    {
        var h = new Outer.Hidden();      // illegal, will not compile
        var s = new Outer.Shady()        // illegal, will not compile
        var p = new Outer.Promiscuous(); // legal
    }
}
```

In essence the only way to achieve what you desire is to use the outer class as a form of namespace and restrict within that class.

Comment: @ShuggyCoUK: public class Sub : Outer should be sealed public class Sub : Outer ???   +1 though...it works for me

Comment: It is possible with friend assemblies. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65751319/8810311

Answer (score 2):

No, it is possible. You can use internal class in another assembly.
For example I have a internal string extension class that located in `SharMillSoft.Core` assembly, if I want use it in another assembly that name is `SharpMilSoft.Extension`, I must use assembly attribute like as below:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("SharpMilSoft.Extensions")]

namespace SharpMilSoft.Core.Extensions.Strings.Public
{
    internal static class SharpStringExtensions
    {
        public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this string data)
        {
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(data);
        }
    }
}
```

And I use this class in `SharpMilSoft.Extension` assembly like as below:

```
namespace SharpMilSoft.Extensions.Strings
{
    public static class SharpStringExtensions
    {
        public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this string data)
        {
            return Core.Extensions.Strings.Public.SharpStringExtensions.IsNullOrEmpty(data);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: Then `SharpMilSoft.Extensions` assembly will be friend assembly for `SharpMilSoft.Core` assembly

For more details about friend assembly, you can visit this link : [Friend assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/friend)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single assembly you can define as many namespaces in that assembly as you want but no matter what modifier you apply in the IDE you will always be able to see the classes in other namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is directly possible, but a few good ways to fake it would be:

1) Have the classes that need this sort of stuff inherit from a single class which has the helper class as an internal class.

2) Use extension methods and then only reference the extension methods within the namespace.