# Difference between private and public access modifier in C#?

Tags: c#, access-modifiers

I understand that if I were to use a *private* access modifier, for example:

```
namepsace MyNameSpace
{
  class Book
  {
   private string title;
  }
}
```

Then this means that the instance variable *title* would only be accessible from within the class i.e the *Book* class in the above example.

However, if I were to make the instance variable *public*, I have read that this makes it accessible to outside of the class.

My question is, does this also mean it is accessible outside of the namespace? Or are we still talking about the classes within the namespace? I couldn't find any resource that answered this question of mine hence thought to ask here.

Comment: Tag this with language that you are using to get the relevant folks to look at it.

Comment: It seems like the [Access Modifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx) reference would explain what you want to know. Always check the docs when you have a question about the language/framework.

Answer (score 2):

Namespaces are purely for organization, not for accessibility.  There are no accessibility mechanisms in .NET that allow/restrict access to resources based on namespace.  Since namespaces can be spread across multiple assemblies, making a member private "to a namespace" would not be effective since anyone could write a class in a different assembly but the same namespace and access those members.

You can infer this from [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) that makes no mention of namespace when discussion accessibility, only types and assemblies.

In general, `private` means "can only be used by the thing that *contains* the definition".  For members, that's the class; for types, it's the "outer" type that defines it, if there is one. You can't have a top-level `private` type since namespaces aren't really "containers" so there's nothing to make it private *to*.

Other questions that address this:

[Namespace only class visibility in C#/.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223873/namespace-only-class-visibility-in-c-net)

[private classes inside namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651543/private-classes-inside-namespaces)

[How do you make infrastructure code only visible in namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540441/how-do-you-make-infrastructure-code-only-visible-in-namespace)

Answer (score 0):

Complete location of `title` is `MyNameSpace::Book::title`. `Namespaces` do not restrict the accessibility of its members. `Namespace` give new location to its members. `class` is also a type of `Namespace`.

For example:

In China there might be a telephone with number `123456789`. Also in Singapore there might be a telephone with same number `123456789`. Any one can dial these numbers. But to distinguish between these different numbers, we need `Country Code` and sometimes `STD Code` as well. So here, `Country Code` and `STD Code` are `Namespace`.

Making a member of `class` `public` won't affect it from getting accessible outside `Namespace`. However, the member access should be valid via object of class.

Comment: This example doesn't really make it clearer I think.

Answer (score 0):

No. It's not about namespace. A namespace is a location. As long as your class is accessed, its' public members will be able to be accessed too.