# How to organise namespaces within an assembly to reflect design

Tags: c#

I would like to organise my assembly so the code that I write reflects my intended design. From help I already received I understand that namespaces are the principal way to organise types to achieve this.

The issue I have is that my assembly, `Assembly`, say, uses a layer of implementation classes. However some of the classes in `Layer1` are themselves part of the implementation of `Layer1` and I'd like to reflect that in the way I structure my code. My first thought was to try to make some classes in `Layer1` private, but I can see that [this is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223873/namespace-only-class-visibility-in-c-net).

Logically, `Layer1` is exposing classes `A1`, `B1`, `C1` etc. And it uses classes `A2`, `B2`, `C2` etc.

```
namespace Assembly.Layer1
{
    // "interface to Layer1"
    class A1 // ...
    class B1 // ...
    class C1 // ...
    // "implementation of Layer1"
    class A2 // ...
    class B2 // ...
    class C2 // ...
} // (one file per class)
```

It seems like one way to address this is to put `A2`, `B2`, `C2` etc into a new namespace, `Assembly.Layer1.Layer2`. Then, when I'm writing code in the top-level namespace and using `Assembly.Layer1`, intellisense only shows me the classes that `Assembly.Layer1` exposes. Also, *by convention*, I should only refer one layer down in the namespace hierarchy at a time. Is this the right approach?

Comment: +1 for the effort on the question but it does seem a little abstract and contrived. So I'm finding it hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: you can declare classes within classes.

Comment: @Jodrell thanks, I tend to worry a lot about dependencies in my code and how to make them explicit, maybe a bit too much? The code above is abstract, but I derived it from a real assembly I have where I have already have an implementation namespace of 9 classes, of which several are only used in the implementation. I'm looking for an way of making this clear, so that the design is obvious to other programmers, and to me when I come back to it.

Comment: @Jodrell thanks, nested classes could do it, and might be applicable for the assembly I'm currently working on, but I don't think they would generalize particularly well if my implementation layer comprised a group of classes that referenced each other.

Comment: If you want to *enforce* layers and hide internal details you will want to use Assemblies not just Namespaces.  Use `internal` for the '2' classes.

Comment: @Ian Mercer cheers, good to get a negative answer so i know what's possible and what isn't